# Can I use a custom Splash screen?

Tags: customization

The default Splash screens are cool, but I'd like to add some of my own work to remind me of how awesome I am (no, not really).

[image]

Is it possible to customize/change the splash screen?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**You have to build this with Blender.**

It is located at `/blender/release/datafiles/splash.png` — [(old svn link)](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/blender/release/datafiles/splash.png) [(new git link)](http://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/release/datafiles/splash.png).

Just replace<sup>1</sup> this file with a similar one.

[image]

- <sup>1</sup>Here is a link to the entry on the [wiki](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.4/Doc/How_to/Edit_the_SplashScreen) on how to correctly change it.
- You can grab an old [template](http://download.blender.org/demo/test/splash_template_2.50.png) here which should still work and size your image accordingly ([src](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?225288-Blender-2.59-splash-contest)). The template is also in the same directory as `splash_template.xcf`
- BlenderCookie has a [tutorial on building Blender](https://vimeo.com/16190129) ([download from archives](https://cgcookie.com/archive/building-blender-in-osx/)) in which the author changes the splash screen. *(He uses mac but the majority of process can be done pretty much the same way for other platforms)*

Comment: Currently, more cmake is used, how would you do it?

Comment: This is cool! I have been wondering if you could do this.

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 Yep and now that blender is super easy to build you can literally download some tools and type a few commands and that's it.

Answer (score 9):

You can do that with a custom build of blender.

The image is located in the source at: /blender/blender/release/datafiles/splash.png

If you're interested here's a link on how to build blender from source: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender

If your on Mac, CGCookie has a [tutorial](https://vimeo.com/16190129) ([archive](https://cgcookie.com/archive/building-blender-in-osx/)) on how to build blender with custom splash screen.

Comment: Currently, more cmake is used, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to use [Application Templates](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html) with custom splash screen.

On Windows you would create a `bl_app_templates_user` folder in your preferences scripts folder - `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\startup\bl_app_templates_user\` This folder can contain a folder with your template with startup file, add-ons, themes, keymaps and other things and if you include a custom 1000x500px png image called `splash.png`, it's going to be the splash screen if you start Blender with `--app-template your_template_name` argument (template name is the name of the template folder in `bl_app_templates_user\`). You can see system templates in Blender's installation directory(something like `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\startup\bl_app_templates_system`) and could copy one to start creating your own from it). So after creating a template just make a Windows shortcut with a target like `"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\blender.exe" --app-template my_template` and use it to start Blender:

[image]