# How to modify the Splash Screen?

Tags: interface, customization

Is there any source code for the splash screen ( version 2.77a )? I want to change some parts of it i.e. remove the "links" section

Also, I want to change the picture. I saw [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/188/can-i-use-a-custom-splash-screen) but in the 2.77 version, there isn't any *splash.jpg* file

[image]

Comment: blender/release/datafiles/splash.png is the image. https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Doc/How_to/Edit_the_SplashScreen

Comment: @batFINGER what is this ? deleted :|

Comment: blender/source/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_operators.c seems to be the place for splash, around line 1800. Note that C/C++ questions are offtopic for the site though.

Comment: Yeah, it's the snippet of info ‎"Editing the splash screen is no longer done this way,. you only have to edit the PNG image, the build system handles the rest.".